# Decoding contract output of web3 eth call

Tags: web3js, abi, calldata

I have written data to a contract using sendRawTransaction, and am trying to fetch it using web3.eth.call for the function :
`function checkRecord(uint id, bytes email) constant returns (uint id2, bytes email2, bytes hash) {..}`

I create call data as
`var callData = contract.checkRecord.getData(id, email)`
to get
'0xf1e8a43c0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000004000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000156d617467656f2e3230303840676d61696c2e636f6d0000000000000000000000'

and fetch result as
result = web3.eth.call({'to': address, 'from': account, 'data': callData})

where result is
'0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000006000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000a000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000156d617467656f2e3230303840676d61696c2e636f6d00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000'

How do i decode the result back to (uint, bytes, bytes) ?

Answer (score 5):

you can use web3 built-in functionality:

```
web3.eth.abi.decodeParameters(typesArray, hexString);
```

see [link](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth-abi.html#decodeparameters)

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is to use "**abi-decoder**".
I forked the repository and created index.html for easy usage.

You can download and use it from:
https://github.com/Muhammad-Altabba/abi-decoder (you can later check it at https://github.com/ConsenSys/abi-decoder once they will accept my pull request)

To download and run using NPM:

```
npm install abi-decoder
bower install abi-decoder
```

Then download https://github.com/Muhammad-Altabba/abi-decoder/index.html to the same directory. Then open the file "index.html" in browser.

You will get:

[image: abi-decoder index.html]

Answer (score 1):

As the [web3 documentation](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#web3ethcall) points out web3.eth.call returns a `String`, which is the returned data of the call, e.g. a codes functions return value. In your case the result string contains a `uint` (which is an alias for `uint256`) and two dynamically-sized byte arrays.

Split the result into 32-byte chunks and then apply a `toAscii(hexString)` function on the chunks.

With this method you'll get that the `uint` is the number 2 padded with zeroes, it looks like this: `0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002`.
The first byte array is {96,160,21,matgeo.2008@gmail.com}. The second byte array contains only zeros.

Comment: `toAscii` is deprecated. Use `hexToAscii` in web3 v1. `web3.utils.hexToAscii(0x....)
`